# How can I dynamically access a JSON file generated by Unity in an Android Studio app?

Tags: android, file, unity-game-engine

Hy there!

I have a project with Unity for android and another with Android Studio.

The Unity project generate a json file in their package storage and i need to access to that file with the other app of Android Studio.

The problem is that the path changes in each model of mobile so i can't have a static string for the file path and i need it to show the data of the json in that app.

I just try a lot of things but without any success.

Hope you can help me with it, is a part of the final project of my studies and i need to connect the apps without internet.

Thanks in advance.

I expect to find a way to have the path of the file in a dynamic way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.